# Simple search page.

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace RideShare.Web
{
    public partial class UserOrganization : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    // Fill drop down in search area.
                    FillOrganizationDropDown();

                    // Populate riders grid with all records in Riders table.
                    PopulateRidersGrid((int)SearchArguments.Zeor, null, (int)SearchArguments.Zeor, (int)SearchArguments.GenderDefaultValue);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Exceptions.CatchException(false, ex);
            }
        }

        // Populate drop down list with organizations in each row bound.
        // Select Organization in drop down if rider has one.
        protected void grdRiders_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    DropDownList ddlRiderOrganization = e.Row.FindControl("ddlRiderOrganization") as DropDownList;

                    if (ddlRiderOrganization != null)
                    {
                        PopulateGridOrgDropDown(ddlRiderOrganization);

                        // This is needed to select the organization of rider in ddl in grid
                        Label lblOrganizationId = e.Row.FindControl("lblOrganizationId") as Label;

                        if (lblOrganizationId != null)
                        {
                            if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblOrganizationId.Text.Trim())))
                            {
                                ddlRiderOrganization.SelectedValue = lblOrganizationId.Text;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Exceptions.CatchException(false, ex);
            }
        }

        // Update organization when user click on update button.
        protected void grdRiders_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.CommandName == "UpdateOrganization")
                {
                    int rowIndex = -1;
                    rowIndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

                    if (rowIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        GridViewRow row = grdRiders.Rows[rowIndex];

                        // Get organization id from ddl
                        int seletedOrganizationId = GetSelecetdOrgId(row);

                        // Organization is selected in drop down.
                        if (seletedOrganizationId > 0)
                        {
                            int riderId = GetRiderId(row);

                            if (riderId > 0)
                            {
                                bool isUpdate = RidersService.UpdateRiderOrganization(riderId, seletedOrganizationId);

                                ShowMessage(isUpdate);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Exceptions.CatchException(false, ex);
            }
        }

        // Filter grid on given criteria.
        protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                FilterGrid();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Exceptions.CatchException(false, ex);
            }
        }

        // Put all controls on default position and populate grid.
        protected void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                txtName.Text = "";
                txtAge.Text = "";
                ddlGender.SelectedValue = "-1";

                ddlOrganization.SelectedIndex = 0;
                FilterGrid();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Exceptions.CatchException(false, ex);
            }
        }

        // Filter Riders grid on changing organizaton.
        protected void ddlOrganization_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                FilterGrid();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Exceptions.CatchException(false, ex);
            }
        }

        // Fitler grid on search criteria specified.
        private void FilterGrid()
        {
            int organizationId = 0;
            int.TryParse(ddlOrganization.SelectedValue.ToString(), out organizationId);

            string name = "";
            if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text.Trim())))
            {
                name = txtName.Text.Trim();
            }

            int age = 0;
            if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAge.Text.Trim())))
            {
                int.TryParse(txtAge.Text.Trim(), out age);
            }

            int gender = int.Parse(ddlGender.SelectedValue.ToString());

            PopulateRidersGrid(organizationId, name, age, gender);
        }

        // Fill grid with riders.
        private void PopulateRidersGrid(int organizationId, string firstName, int age, int gender)
        {
            grdRiders.DataSource = RidersService.GetRidersOnOrganizationId(organizationId, firstName, age, gender);
            grdRiders.DataBind();
        }

        // Fill Organizations drop down. This drop down is in search area.
        private void FillOrganizationDropDown()
        {
            // Append is to retain an item i.e. 'All' having '0' value.
            ddlOrganization.AppendDataBoundItems = true;

            ddlOrganization.DataTextField = "OrganizationName";
            ddlOrganization.DataValueField = "OrganizationId";

            ddlOrganization.DataSource = RidersService.GetAllOrganization();
            ddlOrganization.DataBind();
        }

        // Populate organization drop down in gridview.
        private void PopulateGridOrgDropDown(DropDownList ddlRiderOrganization)
        {
            ddlRiderOrganization.DataTextField = "OrganizationName";
            ddlRiderOrganization.DataValueField = "OrganizationId";

            ddlRiderOrganization.DataSource = RidersService.GetAllOrganization();
            ddlRiderOrganization.DataBind();
        }

        // Get organization id from drown down in grid.
        private int GetSelecetdOrgId(GridViewRow row)
        {
            int selectedOrganizationId = -1;

            // Capture organization drop down list of current row.
            DropDownList ddlRiderOrganization = row.FindControl("ddlRiderOrganization") as DropDownList;

            if (ddlRiderOrganization != null)
            {
                selectedOrganizationId = int.Parse(ddlRiderOrganization.SelectedValue.ToString());
            }

            return selectedOrganizationId;
        }

        // Get rider id from specified grid row.
        private int GetRiderId(GridViewRow row)
        {
            int riderId = 0;

            Label lblRiderId = row.FindControl("lblRiderId") as Label;

            if (lblRiderId != null)
            {
                if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblRiderId.Text)))
                {
                    riderId = int.Parse(lblRiderId.Text);
                }
            }

            return riderId;
        }

        private void ShowMessage(bool isUpdated)
        {
            if (isUpdated)
            {
                ltrlMessage.Text = "Organization Updated Successfully!";
            }
            else
            {
                ltrlMessage.Text = "Organization Not Updated. Please contact support team!";
            }
        }

        private enum SearchArguments : int
        {
            GenderDefaultValue = -1,
            Zeor = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does this code do Exceptions.CatchException(false, ex);

Comment: @Jethro, this is where I Log exceptions in text file.

Comment: can I ask why you are always setting the CatchException(false.

Comment: @Jethro, there is nothing special I am using this flag to show or not show the Error Page.

Comment: small suggestion then would be to add this to the Application session if it's a global variable, or to a user session if it's per user setting, this way if you want to show the error you don't have to go to every page and change that hard coded false to a true.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend that you register your methods as event handlers. You have several handlers that merely call more descriptive methods, which clutters up the code a bit. In `Page_Load()`:

```
// Register event handlers
btn_Search.Click += new EventHandler(this.FilterGrid);
btn_Clear.Click += new EventHandler(this.ClearGrid);
```

And so on for each event. (ClearGrid is hypothetical - not one you already have implemented.) This ought to condense the source quite a bit. You might lose some of the Visual Studio navigation options; IMO it's worth it for a cleaner code-behind.

Oh, and you've misspelled `GetSelecetdOrgId` :)

Comment: Thanks for your time and reviewing it. By admitting my little knowledge I just want to ask that can you please provide me more information on "register your methods as event handlers". Tutorial, blog post etc. So I have clear understanding that what benefits this technique has so I use this with more understanding. I don't want to know that HOW to do this I want to know WHY to do this. Thanks again.